# How to delete columns from a data extension using SDK

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, sdk

For example, there is a data extension has three columns, how can I remove AGE column?

```
FN  |LN   |AGE
Jack|Johns|12
Jane|Jones|24
Luke|Smith|15
```

Comment: The first question i would have asked, if i knew more about sdk's is which SDK you are referring to. There are quite a few.

Comment: it's https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/FuelSDK-Java